# BigQuery: Union / Join two tables with many columns, some overlapping

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two large tables with some overlapping columns, some of which contain the same values in the overlapping columns. Here's a toy example (in the actual example, there are dozens of columns, both those that overlap and those that don't):

```
Table 1: a, b, c

Table 2: a, d, e
```

Some values of `a` are in only one table, some are in both.

Is there a query that will let me generate a table with all values where available:

```
Table 3: a, b, c, d, e
```

My current query requires listing every column, which is very verbose with dozens of columns, and inflexible when the schema changes:

```
SELECT
  coalesce(t1.a,
    t2.a) AS a,
  t1.b,
  t1.c,
  t2.d,
  t2.e
FROM
  t1
FULL JOIN
  t2
USING
  (a)
```

Things I've tried: `UNION` seems to require the same schema, `SELECT t1.*, t2.*` raises an error on overlapping columns, `SELECT t1.* ... USING (a)` will give nulls for values in `a` where there are values only in `t1.a`.

Comment: you need to have at least one column in each table to use as a join key. is it `a` column? but from your last sentence in question it looks like it is not? and do you actually need a join or union? if you provide some examples of input and output  - this would address some of those

Comment: Yes, each of these is a column. `a` is the join key here. 

I don't _need_ a join - there are no rows that take information from both tables.

Does that make sense? I updated the last sentence to hopefully clarify

Answer (score 2):

Before BigQuery Standard SQL got available to all of us in June 2, 2016 - I was extremely happy with what now called BigQuery Legacy SQL. I still enjoy it time by time for some specific use cases

I think the case you described in your question is exactly one where you can leverage feature of Legacy SQL to resolve your issue

So, below is for BigQuery Legacy SQL

```
#legacySQL
SELECT * 
FROM [project:dataset.table1],
  [project:dataset.table2]
```

Note: in BigQuery Legacy SQL comma - `,` - means `UNION ALL`

Super-simplified example of above is

```
#legacySQL
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT1 a, 2 b, 3 c, 11 x),
 (SELECT 1 a, 4 d, 5 e, 12 x)
```

with result

```
Row     a   b       c       x       d       e    
1       1   2       3       11      null    null     
2       1   null    null    12      4       5
```

Note: you cannot mix Legacy and Standard SQL in same query, so if you need use Standard SQL against resulted UNION - you will need first to materialize(save) result as a table and then query that table using Standard SQL

> Is there any way with Standard SQL

You can use [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables) to script out columns from both tables and built list of all involved columns - but you sutill will need then to copy-paste result into final query to run it

Comment: That's great! Thank you. Is there any way with Standard SQL?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think so - at least in easy - one query way! let's see what other experts here will say :o) meantime, consider voting up the answer

Comment: by "easy - one query way" I meant obviously this can be addressed by scripting with client of your choice - but from your question it didn't sound you wanted going this way.